# Has anyone managed to start the Imperial event yet?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I got the following message from the Emperor when I started my TDS. Except this message and the fact that there are now red banners in my lift lobby, there is no other sign that this event had even started. I checked the App Store and there is no new updates for TDS too. Has anyone else managed to get this event started yet?

[image: Emperor message]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I just saw the Imperial officer icon (on the top right side of the game screen) right across the Emperor icon and clicked on it. I then summoned a decorator droid for it (it's a black astromech droid) but the droid didn't appear automatically. You would have to go to your VIP lounge to get him out.

But I've only met this decorator droid randomly once despite playing quite regularly, unlike the last two events where the decorator droids appear much more frequently. May have to spend bux if I want to get all the rewards (which may be what the devs are aiming for).

Anyone notice the decorator droids rarely turned up, at least compared to the past 2 events?

Comment: It hasn't been much time yet, but it seems on par with the christmas droids so far. i didn't feel like those were super-common for me either.

Comment: Alex, how many droids have u gotten this time round? I've only gotten 3 so far, including the free one which I summoned. It really feels less frequent than the Christmas droids...

Comment: Yeah, after a few days have gone by, i think you're right. I got a couple fairly quickly, but it's been dry since then.

Comment: I haven't measured it exactly but I seem to only be getting about 1 free droid per day.  That's with at least 2-3 hours of active play time per day.  Looks like I'm going to be spending a lot of bux on this one.  At least it's better than gambling them on the salvage droids.

Comment: I think 1 free droid or maybe 2 a day at most feels about right. I've gotten 36 droids so far and I bought at least 30 with bux... I've got enough bux saved up to hit the next target at 60 droids, but will put off spending bux to get them til the last day.

Comment: Agreed.  I'm waiting until the last day to spend the bux just in case this is a "bug" and they increase the rate of free droids before then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing and the app would also crash a lot (about at the same frequency I should have gotten a decorator droid). I closed the app and went into the app settings and cleared the cache (android) and that seems to have fixed it. The decorator droid showed up in the next dozen or so elevators and it has stopped crashing.